# How can a share price always have exact even values?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, shares

I have a share of [Audi](https://www.audi.com/en/company/investor-relations/audi-shares.html), and have been puzzled by the fact that beginning with January 2018 until now, it has always had whole even Euro values – currently 804.00 €. How is this possible? What keeps traders from selling at different prices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote to Audi Investor Relations and they provided a quite detailed answer. It turns out that there are "tick sizes" for shares as per [European Union regulation 2017/588](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/GA/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32017R0588), which came into effect from 2018 on and has larger tick sizes for for expensive shares and shares with lower trade volumes; hence it is especially noticable for an expensive share with very limited free floating shares (0.36 %) like Audi's.

The table of tick sizes for various price ranges is found [in the annex](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/GA/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32017R0588#d1e32-416-1).

Answer (score 1):

Some exchanges have quotation rules that could force that to happen. Audi is listed on several exchanges, some European, some US. On the US exchange there are plenty of quotes that are not even numbers.

There could also be liquidity issues on some exchanges.

There could also be the fact people just don't want to trade at non-even prices, which could be related to liquidity issues.

Comment: Added link to https://www.audi.com/en/company/investor-relations/audi-shares.html , which makes it most obvious. All the Euro exchanges have slightly different prices, but all are whole even Euro values.

Answer (score -3):

I'm puzzled by your question.  The link that you provided opens up a chart which defaults to one day (no chart). If you click on any number of days other than one day. it displays a graph of different prices on different days.

On the days when  there were no trades, the close remains the same and the graph is horizontal.

You can see the historical prices and daily volume at [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AUDVF/history?p=AUDVF).

Comment: The OP is asking why the shares trade in whole dollars.

Comment: @Lawrence - If you had clicked on his link and looked at the chart, you'd have seen that it has not traded in 'whole' dollars on the few occasions that shares crossed hands. And if you had clicked on my link and looked at the historical data, you'd have seen that it has not traded in 'whole' dollars on the few occasions that shares crossed hands.  Yes, perhaps two different markets but no, not trading in 'whole' dollars'.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't realize the link would display dollar values when accessed from another location. I clarified the question. The share is traded in Euros, and indeed always has not just whole, but even (so odd values are skipped) whole Euro values. This is evident not only from Google, but also from my bank's charts.

Comment: @BobBaerker My previous comment was trying to clarify what I thought was a misunderstanding of the question - the OP seemed to be concerned about “even values”, not a lack of “different prices”.